# Change column value based on list pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am looking to keep track of customers that are going to churn in 2019 in the order data of 2018 so that I can do some analyses such as where the customers come from, if their order size has been decreasing compared to customers that will not churn.

The orderdata in 2018 is a pandas df called 'order_data' and I have a list of customers that will churn in 2019 called 'churn_customers_2019'. In order_data there is a column called Customer_id. The list is also filled with Customer_id names of the clients that will churn.

However my logic is not running well.

```
order_data['churn in 2019?'] = str('N')

for x in order_data['Customer_id']:
    if x in churn_customers_2019:
        order_data['churn in 2019?'][x] = 'Y'
```

If I run this code everything changes to N instead of also having some Y. Only about 10% of the customers churn.

Comment: Hi there, can you provice a [mcve] you need to add a sample dataset with your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for your problem, likewise:

```
order_data['churn in 2019?'] = np.where(order_data['Customer_id'].isin(churn_customers_2019), 'Y', 'N')
```

Comment: Thank you! This works and also simplified my code!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)